# Workaround for storing an original enum constant value to be used later?

Tags: java, object, reference, enums

For example, I have an enum

```
public enum DistanceUnits
{
    METER, KILOMETER, MILE;
}
```

I have a global reference type of it `DistanceUnits distanceUnit;`. At some point of time it is set to some constant value say `distanceUnit = DistanceUnits.METER`. Now if I want to work temporarily and globally with another constant value say `distanceUnit = DistanceUnits.KILOMETER`. But after the temporary process, I want to get back to my original value which is `distanceUnit = DistanceUnits.METER`. How to store `distanceUnit = DistanceUnits.METER` so that it can be recovered again.

I know this is due to the rules of the java language that deal with reference types. So is there a workaround for this issue?.

Another questions:
- If there is a possible workaround for this problem. Is it applicable for java objects also?
- If there is a possible workaround for java objects but not applicable for enums then share it?

Comment: A stack might be useful.

Comment: Can you show a simple example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Store it in another variable? `DistanceUnit backup = distanceUnit; doSomeWorkWhichChangesDistanceUnit(); distanceUnit = backup;`. What's the problem?

Comment: @JBNizet The problem is that if I change `distanceUnit` to the new value then `backup` will also refer to the new value, not the original value. And this doesn't solve the problem!.

Comment: No, it won't. You don't seem to understand how Java references work. They're just like C pointers, not like C++ references.

Comment: @JBNizet You are right. The problem is very easy. It is some misconception from me towards java basics happened at some moment.  The question doesn't worth to be asked at all. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @SotiriosDelimanolis says, a stack *might* be a good way to handle this. It would look something like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    private static final LinkedList<DistanceUnit> stack = new LinkedList<>();
    static DistanceUnit distanceUnit = DistanceUnit.METER;

    static void pushAndSetUnit(DistanceUnit newUnit) {
        stack.push(distanceUnit);
        distanceUnit = newUnit;
    }

    static void popUnit() {
        distanceUnit = stack.pop();
    }
}
```

Your "temporary processes" would look like this:

```
pushAndSetUnit(...);
try {
    ...
} finally {
    popUnit();
}
```

The try-finally ensures pop is called even if the process throws an exception. You can have temporary processes called within other temporary processes, because the stack is unbounded.

It seems to me like a serious code smell though, depending on this mutable global behavior setting. It's *extremely* unwieldy. You would be much better off if you could just provide a different DistanceUnit value to each class that needs it, instead of adjusting a single global variable.

> I know this is due to the rules of the java language that deal with reference types.

No it isn't. It has nothing to do with enums, or reference types at all. This works just as well and just as badly with any type of variable.